# ERR_UNSUPPORTED_ESM_URL_SCHEME - next-sitemap

Tags: javascript, next.js, sitemap

I'm using [next-sitemap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-sitemap/v/1.6.228).
node version:
v14.11.0

```
next-sitemap.config.js

module.exports = {
    siteUrl: 'https://*****.com',
    generateRobotsTxt: true,
    robotsTxtOptions: {
      additionalSitemaps: [
        'https://*****.com/server-sitemap-index.xml', // <==== Add here
      ],
    },
  }
```

inside this file:

pages/server-sitemap-index.xml/index.ts

```
// @ts-nocheck
import { getServerSideSitemapIndex } from 'next-sitemap'
import { GetServerSideProps } from 'next'
import { baseApiURL } from "src/utiles/constants.js";
export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async (ctx) => {
  // Method to source urls from cms
  const res = await axios(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_API}dental/generic/wide-range-of-services/`);
  const { data } = res.data;
  const fields = data.map((item) => ({
    loc: `${process.env.SITE_URL}service/${item.slug}`,
    lastmod: 'item.updatedAt',
    priority: 0.7,
    changefreq: "daily",
  }));

  console.log({ fields });

  return getServerSideSitemapIndex(ctx, services)
}

// Default export to prevent next.js errors
export default function SitemapIndex() {}
```

package.json:

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "postbuild": "next-sitemap",
        ...
```

but when I want to build I got this error:

```
next-sitemap
internal/process/esm_loader.js:74
    internalBinding('errors').triggerUncaughtException(
                              ^

Error [ERR_UNSUPPORTED_ESM_URL_SCHEME]: Only file and data URLs are supported by the default ESM loader. Received protocol 'node:'
    at Loader.defaultResolve [as _resolve] (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:751:11)
    at Loader.resolve (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:85:40)
    at Loader.getModuleJob (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:229:28)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:51:40)
    at link (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:50:36) {
  code: 'ERR_UNSUPPORTED_ESM_URL_SCHEME'
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! dental@0.1.0 postbuild: `next-sitemap`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the dental@0.1.0 postbuild script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Minimum supported node version is `node: >=14.18`

Answer (score 0):

Please check the version of Node.js that is listed in the package.json file and put it on the device you are using.

Once I installed the same version that was listed in the package, it worked for me.json, the problem was fixed.

I hope this helps.